# How many even numbers greater than 50 000 can be formed from specified digits without repeat?

Tags: permutations

The digits are 3,4,5,6,7,0

My working is as follows:

I realize that you would need to start with either 5,6 or 7.
From there you have 5 digits to re-arrange, but the permutation would have to end in an even number.

Starting with 5 you would end with either 4, 6 or 0;
Thus you would have 4 digits left to permute and 3 even numbers to end with so: **(4!)(3)**

Starting with 6 you would end with 4 or 0;
Thus **(4!)(2)**

Starting with 7 would be the same as with 5.

In the end my answer was **(4!)(3) + (4!)(2) + (4!)(3) = 192.**
The answer given in my text book is **504.**

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you forgot that you have 6 digits to use. The first number is indeed 5 digits starting with 5, ending with 6 (50346), but the highest one is 765430 (6 digits)... You need to compute the number of 5 digits numbers plus the number of 6 digits ones, that can start with 3 and 4... EDIT: If you HAVE to use the six numbers, the 0 can be placed first to do 5 digits numbers, but they can't finish with 0...

Comment: Thank you, it seems so obvious on a second glance! I realized my mistake this morning after reviewing the question again but thank you for the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add up the following:

- Amount of 5-digit numbers that start with $5$ and end with $0$ is $\binom{4}{3}\cdot3!$
- Amount of 5-digit numbers that start with $5$ and end with $4$ is $\binom{4}{3}\cdot3!$
- Amount of 5-digit numbers that start with $5$ and end with $6$ is $\binom{4}{3}\cdot3!$
- Amount of 5-digit numbers that start with $6$ and end with $0$ is $\binom{4}{3}\cdot3!$
- Amount of 5-digit numbers that start with $6$ and end with $4$ is $\binom{4}{3}\cdot3!$
- Amount of 5-digit numbers that start with $7$ and end with $0$ is $\binom{4}{3}\cdot3!$
- Amount of 5-digit numbers that start with $7$ and end with $4$ is $\binom{4}{3}\cdot3!$
- Amount of 5-digit numbers that start with $7$ and end with $6$ is $\binom{4}{3}\cdot3!$
- Amount of 6-digit numbers that start with anything but $0$ and end with $0$ is $5!$
- Amount of 6-digit numbers that start with anything but $0$ and end with $4$ is $5!-4!$
- Amount of 6-digit numbers that start with anything but $0$ and end with $6$ is $5!-4!$

So the overall amount is $24+24+24+24+24+24+24+24+120+96+96=504$.

Comment: Oops, didn't notice the *even*!!!

Comment: @Marco13: Oops, didn't notice the *even* :) Now fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The number can have 5 or 6 digits and can not begin with 0

1. the numbers with 5 digits being even;
   1*4*3*2*2 =48
2. the numbers with 5 digits being odd;
   3*4*3*2*2=144
3. the numbers with 6 digits being even;
   2*4*3*2*1*2=96
4. the numbers with 6 digits being odd;
   3*4*3*2*1*3=216
   Therefore there are 48+144+96+216=504 possibilities